# neo4j: Setting apoc.create.uuid() on the outside causes replacement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sorry don't exactly know what title i should put. Using query below to explain.

```
       UNWIND $data as data
       MERGE (d:Device {cell_id: data.cell_id})
       ON CREATE SET d+= data
       WITH d
       SET d._uuid = apoc.create.uuid()
       MERGE (g:Device_Group {group_name: $GROUP_NAME})
       WITH g,d
       MERGE (g)-[:GROUPS]->(d)
```

The cell data I receive is updated frequently and sometimes new devices are added. I also want to set a UUID to each corresponding device. As such I use apoc.create.uuid(). However when the device is updated a new uuid is created that replaces the old one. My issue is that I don't want the UUID to change every time the device is updated.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move set UUID inside `ON CREATE SET` so it would only add UUID when the node is created and ignore it when node is updated.

```
UNWIND $data as data
MERGE (d:Device {cell_id: data.cell_id})
ON CREATE SET 
    d+= data,
    d._uuid = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH d
MERGE (g:Device_Group {group_name: $GROUP_NAME})
WITH g,d
MERGE (g)-[:GROUPS]->(d)
```